# Issue in allowing deselection of a checkbox after applying validation function React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, checkbox, ecmascript-6

I have a selection limit function which ensures that total checked checkbox is above min value and under max value, these values were taken from the JSON which the checkboxes are mapped from, but my problem occurs if the minimum is above 1, as the function does -1 so if the minimum was 2 it leaves a remainder of 1 checked box. You can see from the demo the difference between orders 1 and orders 2.

Full Code: https://codesandbox.io/embed/zo27pvx8l?fontsize=14

**Note**: I am allowing deselecting on purpose for adding warning signs later on and giving the ability to switch between the selected options, I am trying to find a logical approach where anything can be unselected regardless of the minimum.

**Function**

```
selectData(id, event) {
    let isSelected = event.currentTarget.checked;
    if (isSelected) {
      if (this.state.currentData < this.props.max) {
        this.setState({ currentData: this.state.currentData + 1 });
      } else {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.currentTarget.checked = false;
      }
    } else {
      if (this.state.currentData >= this.props.min) {
        this.setState({ currentData: this.state.currentData - 1 });
      } else {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.currentTarget.checked = true;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I was unable to find the error. Can you post a step-by-step on how to reproduce it ?

Comment: @EduardoJunior Orders 1 and Orders 4 works fine because the minimum is 1, but Orders 2 and Orders 3 where the minimum is above 1, if you select more than one option and you try to deselect them, you will end up with options which you cant unselect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So generally speaking getting the state from the dom elements is going to give you a headache. Just keep track of what has and hasn't been clicked in an array, and set the `checked` prop based on if it's in the array or not.

Then you don't need to increment or decrement anything, just check the array length to know if it's above or below the min / max props.

step 1: add array for keeping track of checked stuff

```
this.state = {
   .. other stuff ..
   checkedList: []
};
```

step 2: set the checked value based on if it's in the array

```
<input
  ...
  checked={this.state.checkedList.includes(
    this.props.childk + (item.name || item.description)
  )}
  ...
/>
```

step 3: simplify your onChange handler:

```
selectData(id) {
  if (
    !this.state.checkedList.includes(id) &&
    this.state.checkedList.length < this.props.max
  ) {
    this.setState({ checkedList: [...this.state.checkedList, id] });
  } else if (this.state.checkedList.includes(id)) {
    this.setState({
      checkedList: this.state.checkedList.filter(x => x !== id)
    });
  }
}
```

step 4: make your onChange handler match

```
<input
  ...
  onChange={() =>
    this.selectData(
      this.props.childk + (item.name || item.description)
    )
  }
  ...
/>
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zqp2r70o94)

Comment: thank you for your answer, As for your selectdata function, i did not notice any use of this.props.min, which confused my understanding of what exactly is happening in the function. It do work but i dont understand it. can you explain it ?

Comment: you don't need to handle any `min` logic while the user is selecting items. you can have 0 selected or max selected, but not more than max. eventually you would submit the form and then you could warn the user if they have not selected at least min items.